# Do I still need sessions if I use token based authentication

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, express, jwt

Am I right if I use token based authentication like JWT, in a completely stateless way (ie. include things like user id in the token), then there's no need for sessions at all?

I have just read this article ([Stop using JWT for sessions](http://cryto.net/~joepie91/blog/2016/06/13/stop-using-jwt-for-sessions/)), which does not recommend using JWT to replace sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer (as always): it depends!

<sub>The previous statement is probably the only rule of software development, everything else are guidelines. Yes, I'm exaggerating, but what I want to convey is that you need to take those articles with a grain of salt.</sub>

A more concrete answer to your question would be, yes, if you include everything you need within a JWT you don't need a server-side session, but that's also true if you include everything you need within a cookie.

In your position, I would read a few more articles about that topic and then would think about the specific scenario at hand and decide the approach that would suit it best. I can recommend as an interesting complementary read, the following blog post: [Cookies vs Tokens: The Definitive Guide](https://auth0.com/blog/cookies-vs-tokens-definitive-guide/)

> **TL;DR** Tokens-based authentication is more relevant than ever. We examine the differences and similarities between cookie and token-based authentication, advantages of using tokens, and address common questions and concerns developers have regarding token-based auth.

As you can see from the summary, it seems to favor token-based authentication, but that's good because it will allow you to get another perspective on the subject.

Personally I would have no issues in using either one of those methodologies depending on the scenario.

If my **system is comprised of a single or even multiple web applications that are made available in a single domain** the more traditional implementation of using session identifiers with the associated session data stored on the server is a damn good option, let's see why:

- You can have single sign-on across your system because your session cookie can be made available to all applications inside the same domain.
- There's the overhead of maintaining session state on the server, but as long as you do it right you can still scale with that configuration.
- The session identifier will most likely be even more lightweight than a JWT and it will be opaque to the client so you don't have to worry about leaking sensitive information.

However, if I have a **multiple application system spread across different domains and/or platforms (web, native mobile, etc)** I would give more relevance to a token based approach... why you ask, lets see:

- In a system like this is highly likely you'll want to have a Web API common to the different client applications. It's very easy to setup an API to be protected using a token based approach, because there's a lot of sample code out there.
- Being multiple domain and multiple platform I can't get single sign-on with a cookie.
- Now that you have a common API for your apps, it's much easier to open that API to third-party applications if you're using JWT instead of a traditional cookie-based session identifier.